# use of parfor in matlab for a lattice boltzmann code

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

i'm working on lattice boltzmann method and i've written a matlab code.
I would like to parallelize some parts of the code but i'm new to this so i'd appreciate your help.
I'd like to know if it's possible to use the parfor for this part(collision operator):

```
for i=1:lx
    for j=1:ly
        fork=1:9
           f(k,i,j)=f(k,i,j) .* (1 - omega) + omega .* feq(k,i,j);

         end
    end
end
```

I've tried to replace the outermost for loop with a parfor but the code seems to be slower.

any suggestions?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `lx` and `ly`? I could imagine that parfor will actually be slower due to overhead when the for loop is not that big

Comment: lx and ly in the code are set to 400. I've tried to use higher values but the iteration times grows more and more.

Comment: I have just tested it for 1000x1000 and the `parfor` is still slower but relatively it gets closer to `for`. What I noticed though is that `parfor` completely floods my memory with this loop, probably because it is passing big matrices around. Maybe that is the issue?!

Comment: it's strange beacause replacing the outermost for loop and running the algorithm with lx=ly=1000 it takes 33 seconds instead of 0.4 seconds with the for loop!! Moreover you are right about the memory usage.

Comment: Just a quick check:  you do start a matlabpool with multiple processors available, right?  Otherwise using parfor won't do anything useful.

Comment: @nhowe I don't know about the OP, but I did start the pool and still got the issue. (getting 1 vs 14 seconds with 3 cpus for lx=ly=1000)

Comment: @nhowe i'm running the code with my pc which is equipped with a intel core due2 duo.I thought(perhaps wrongly) at least to obtain the same performance as in the case of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this whole operation with a single line of code without the loops:

```
f = f.*(1 - omega) + omega .* feq;
```

On my computer with 2 cores and starting with:

```
f = rand(9,400,400);
feq = rand(9,400,400);

[lx,ly,lz] = size(f);

omega = rand(1);
```

your loop takes 0.087933 seconds, the parfor loop takes 1.166662 seconds, and this method takes 0.009388 seconds.  If you can, always vectorize your code.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I've already vectorize my code and i obtain the same performance as in your case. But I'd like to know why the parfor takes so long to do this computation.

Comment: I think it's the overhead.  Since the actual operation at the center of the loop is very fast, all of the time is taken communicating with the pool, and so there is no benefit to parallelization.  If the operation were something much more taxing, then the overhead time of talking with the pool would be the same, but the slow operation would be done in parallel and and you would see an overall improvement in speed.

Comment: I thought it was as you say so i tried to use larger values of lx and ly but the time it takes to do the computation was bigger and bigger. could you show me your code with the parfor please so i can compare with mine?

Comment: If you increase BOTH indexes, then it will slow down because you (presumably) have a small and finite number of cores available to you, so you're also increasing the overhead at the same time.Try increasing only `ly`, so that you're making the same number of parallel calls.  As you increase `ly`, the time for serial and parallel computation should go up at different rates, with the parallel rate being lower than the serial rate.  For my code, I copy/pasted your code and changed the first `for` to `parfor`.